# How to flip inner corner arc?

Tags: svg

I would like to draw a polygon with rounded corners.

I have path as follows but the inner corner arc seems to be drawn on the opposite side. How to fix this to have rounded corners everywhere?

```
<path d="M25,185 h250 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v90 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-120 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 v90 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-90 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-220 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z" fill="transparent" stroke="black"/>
```

[image]

Comment: 4 arcs with a given radius can be potentially be drawn between a pair of points. The fourth and fifth values of the arc command (0/1 for both) specify which one to draw.

Comment: I know you already solved your problem, but I find [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) a good tool for creating and exploring paths.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by changing arc settings from `a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20` to `a20,20 0 0 0 -20,20`.